# Finding Ω(EA) of a statistical mechanics question

Tags: probability, entropy, statistical-mechanics

**I'm having a bit of trouble understanding this question:**

Consider an isolated system made up of two Einstein solids A and B each containing 2
particles and separated by a diathermal wall. The overall sample space is

$$Ω(E)=\sum_{E(A)}^{\_} Ω_A(E_A) × Ω_B(E − E_A)$$

and the probability of system A having energy $E_A$ is
$$P(E_A) = \frac{|Ω_A(E_A)||Ω_B(E − E_A)|}{|Ω(E)|
}$$

Complete the following table and sketch $P(E_A)$ against $E_A$.

[image]

**I've filled in the table and I believe it looks as follows:**
[image]

**Now the problem I have is finding out what are the actual calculations you do to find the $Ω_A(E_A)$ and $Ω_A(6-E_A)$ values.**

Comment: What's the definition of an Einstein solid you learned? And how many degrees of freedom for your particles? This will determine what the formula for $\Omega$ is.

Comment: @Rashkolnikov my definition of an Einstein solid is                                            Ω=|Ω_A(E_A)||ΩB(E − E_A)|/ |Ω(E)|, and we notes have no mention of the freedom of particles.

Comment: That is not the definition of an Einstein solid. That is the formula for $\Omega$ when you have two subsystems and the total energy is $E$ and the energy in system $A$ is $E_A$. But it doesn't tell us what $\Omega(E_A)$ is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the [wikipage on Einstein solids](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Einstein_solid), we get the formula for $\Omega$ to be

$$\Omega = \frac{(q+N'-1)!}{q!(N'-1)!}$$

where $q$ is the amount of energy quanta that you can distribute over the $N'$ oscillators. Since you don't give enough context, I don't know what $N'$ is for sure. But it seems that if we pick $q=E_A$ and $N'=2$ we get

$$\Omega = \frac{(E_A+1)!}{E_A!(1)!}=E_A+1$$

which corresponds exactly with the numbers you get. This would mean that your Einstein solids are 1D, i.e. there is 1 degree of freedom for each particle.